# Where and how to correctly write a condition in an UPDATE query in postgresql?

Tags: sql, postgresql

There was a moment where I need to calculate the data, but there are empty fields (null) and I wanted him to skip if there is nothing in some fields. Tell me how to prescribe it, otherwise I get an error

ERROR:  division by zero
SQL state: 22012

sql query:

```
UPDATE summary_all_filter_edit SET resul_power = (SELECT round((((all_plats_ok::numeric - all_plats_no::numeric) / all_plats_ok::numeric) * power::numeric), 2) from summary_all_filter_edit su where su.id=summary_all_filter_edit.id);
```

My table: https://dbfiddle.uk/cXyIdMBr

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may try adding a check in the `WHERE` clause which prevents an update in the case where the denominator be zero:

```sql
UPDATE summary_all_filter_edit
SET resul_power = (
    SELECT round((((all_plats_ok::numeric - all_plats_no::numeric) /
                    all_plats_ok::numeric) * power::numeric), 2)
FROM summary_all_filter_edit su
WHERE su.id = summary_all_filter_edit.id AND
      all_plats_ok::numeric != 0);
```

Comment: I got the hint, but here's the mistake -- >
ERROR:  syntax error at or near ";" :(

Comment: Sorry...was missing a closing parenthesis at the end of the update.

Answer (score 1):

Whenever we need to use the division operator, I find it helpful to use `NULLIF` function so that it won't give me a divison by 0 error.
In your query, we could add NULLIF to the denominator, so that the result of divison,will be NULL instead of giving you an error

```
UPDATE summary_all_filter_edit SET resul_power = (SELECT round((((all_plats_ok::numeric - all_plats_no::numeric) / NULLIF(all_plats_ok::numeric,0)) * power::numeric), 2) from summary_all_filter_edit su where su.id=summary_all_filter_edit.id AND all_plats_ok IS NOT NULL);
```